# Does Jetty have requests cache?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, webserver, jetty

I have some tests that run a couple of jetty servlets and send requests to them from other threads.
I often see that as soon as the servlets are started they receive valid requests even before those other threads were started, as if the requests were cached somewhere and re-read when jetty starts.
Could it be? And if so, how can it be disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty does not have request caching.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have an idea why do I see the above behavior?

Comment: nope, I would fire up wireshark and watch the traffic to figure out what is what.  The requests have to come from somewhere, perhaps the other threads you speak of are faster then you think?

Comment: Indeed there is no such thing. It was a problem with my logic. Not removing the question in case someone will ever need to know it too.